# How to correctly receive MSG_FLAGS?

Tags: c, can-bus, socketcan

After sending the message, I am waiting for MSG_CONFIRM.
How to correctly receive MSG_FLAGS?
I don't understand why `temp` is always equal `-1`.

```
struct msghdr msg;
struct sockaddr_can addr;
struct can_frame frame;
struct ifreq ifr
```

- 

```
setsockopt(s, SOL_CAN_RAW, CAN_RAW_ERR_FILTER, &(int){ 1 }, sizeof(int));
setsockopt(s, SOL_CAN_RAW, CAN_RAW_LOOPBACK, &(int){ 1 }, sizeof(int));
setsockopt(s, SOL_CAN_RAW, CAN_RAW_RECV_OWN_MSGS, &(int){ 1 }, sizeof(int));

strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, ifname);
ioctl(s, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr);

addr.can_family = AF_CAN;
addr.can_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;

write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));

temp = recvmsg(s, &msg, MSG_CONFIRM);

printf("%02X \n", temp);
printf("%02X \n", errno);

if (msg.msg_flags==MSG_CONFIRM){
   printf("MSG_CONFIRM"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

`MSG_CONFIRM` is set by `recvmsg()` in `msg.msg_flags` if the CAN frame is a send confirmation, but you cannot pass the flag to `recvmsg()`.

Unfortunately this makes handling send confirmations a bit complex. After `write()`, you may first receive CAN frames from other nodes, which you have to handle or buffer, before you receive the `MSG_CONFIRM` frame corresponding to `write()`. You cannot use `recvmsg()` to just wait for the confirmation and keep the other frames in the kernel buffer,